# Blazer gem chart customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, customization, chartkick

I want to use [blazer gem](https://github.com/ankane/blazer) in my web application but I am stuck with some limitations of blazer gem as I understand.
Right now blazer gem with only specific charts like **Line, Column, Scatter, Pie, Maps, Targets charts**.
I need some more charts like **radar charts** and **pie donut charts** with blazer charts.

Does anyone know how to customize it please let me know?

ruby: 3.0.0

rails: 6.1.3

blazer: 2.4.2

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi, are you sure you mean the charts in Highcharts? I haven't come across the topic of blazer and Highcharts before.

Comment: yes, I am sure, I want some more chats which are not available in the blazer, do you know how to add or customize it? no need for hightcharts if it is available in chartkick then it's also fine.

Comment: I don't have any information about implementation of Highcharts in the Blazer.

Comment: @SebastianHajdus not just HighChart if we can add more charts from chartkick then it's also fine, do you know how to add it?

Comment: I have experience with Highcharts only but not in your case.

Comment: @SebastianHajdus Thanks, no problem, whenever you have any idea then please share it with me.

Comment: this library has a lot of options https://github.com/railsjazz/rails_charts